# Wordpress Custom Table or Custom Post Types?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am using wordpress to make a site which has job posts, and I want to know the best way to go about storing company details, as each job post must be linked to a company.

Normally I would have just set up a companies table in my database, and put a company ID within each job post, then joined to get company details.

However I have often come across the idea that it's not always the best option in Wordpress development to create new tables (such as  [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins)). Instead I would be better using custom post types.

But how would this work to store company details? Would it be right to create a custom post type for companies, and then add a new post for each company? And then use custom fields to store data about each?

Or would I be best off creating new database tables? What is better and why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suppose it is the best to use custom post types with post meta in conjuction with meta boxes. This way, you will be able to manage in ease your companies, and yet, you will be able to operate custom queries on companies via the WP_Query class.

Currently I am building a business directory for a my client, so I decide to use the custom post types because of flexibility. Also I made a custom script for managing company information in conjuction with post meta.

Take a look in the screen shot to undestraint what I mean :

[image]

Note that whenever I like to add new data to companies, I am free to just add some extra meta boxes, and then save the extra data as meta data for the post. This way is matter of minutes to extend a standart data entity.

What you need:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy (optionaly)
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta

I hope you this will help you :)

Comment: Hey this is a great help! thanks, but one last question, how would I link a 'company type post' to a job type post'? so, when a job is posted, what meta is needed to connect it to the company?

Comment: First create the custom post type for companies to become not hierarchical (like pages), so each company operates as a page. Then in your job custom post type, add a meta box, that contains all the companies, and finally choose the appropriate company from there. PN: Don't forget to mark this as answer if you are satisfied :)

Comment: brilliant! perfect answer to solve my problem, thanks

Answer (score 1):

- Create an Custom post type
- add the custom fields to that custom post type for different fields you need,

There is no need of creating table manually,

- http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/
- http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/

and you can apply the sorting on some custom field you added to the post type,

Comment: but then I would need to make a post for every company? How would I link job x to company y? This is what I don't understand

Comment: with Advance custom field you can have a select field in the JOB post type to relate the JOB to a country

Comment: you will create two post type, JOB and COMPANY