# Innerjoin a custom table the normal WP-Query

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

**This is my table:**

Name: `customTable`
Fields: `ID | title | date | content | url`

and now I want to "inner join" this table into the the normal WP-Query, but only when I am in the category "news".

**This is what I have**

```
function meta_filter_posts( $query )
{

   if(is_category('news'))
   {
       // and here I want to add my custom table (like inner join)
       // sorted by date

        $query->set('orderby','date');
        $query->set('order', 'DESC');   

       /*  innerJoin the table customTable */


   }

}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'meta_filter_posts' );
```

Any ideas how to include this table? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can I ask why you are doing it this way (adding another table)? Can you use post_meta or other functions to accomplish what you need versus trying to merge data?

Comment: Trying to help but haven't received any response.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the answer found here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19547093/1361532

This should allow you to purely use WP_Query and its set functions to get exactly what you need to, instead of trying to rebuild the WP_Query object. The only other way I can think to make this work would be a pure query on the database which would seem to be too excessive.