# Add product to customer's cart from WP admin in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

What I would need is possibility to prepare shopping cart content for selected user/customer in WP admin backend.

When they enter their cart page, they should see items/products I added along with items they added to cart, all together.

What would be the most proper way to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: This is a result of this topic: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wc-add-to-cart-as-admin/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's Fully customization as you want.

You can create a simple page in admin where you can select a user from drop down or you can select multi select  drop down of user.

along with that you can get your product list that you want to add.

with all this thing you need to create custom table in database where this all data should store and we can get where we want.

select the user and select the product you want and save it so it will store data in you custom table with flag like pending or anything that can identifies that is not added in users cart yet.

now when user comes in and it's logged in then you need to check for database table, if there is a column of this user with pending flag then you need to add admin added items in users cart and for that you can find so many code.

after adding your product in cart you can change the flag or remain as it is.

you can try this way.

Comment: Although I am still not sure is this best way to do it, I did it this way. On [Wordpress Codex there are three other (more recommended) ways](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin#Saving_Plugin_Data_to_the_Database) of saving custom data when developing plugin, but I couldn't fit my case in any of them, so I did it this way.

On the other hand, [there are people who say this is the best way to store custom WP plugin data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42298311/5038063)

It works fine so far, and I didn't experienced performance or any other issues, so I'll mark this answer as correct.