# Wordpress Best way to store a tabular data to be used in posts

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to create content around top-100 places to visit.

[Sample Data here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0MuY.png)

Basis this data, I'm creating multiple posts where this data will be displayed sorted Alphabetically or by Recommendation Score.

Currently I'm storing this data in a separate table within Wordpress DB, and using custom wp_query to fetch and sort as required.

I'm not sure if this is the most optimal way to do things. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: I asked this question a while back and the suggestion was exactly what you're doing. You can read more about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42297933/what-is-best-practise-for-storing-custom-data-for-wordpress#answer-42298311

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is best practise for storing custom data for Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42297933/what-is-best-practise-for-storing-custom-data-for-wordpress)

Answer (score 0):

You can also check [Custom Post Types](https://wordpress.org/support/article/post-types/#custom-post-types)

Answer (score 0):

Your two options are to do what you're doing, a custom table, or create a custom post type and use the WP posts table. If you need specific columns in the DB which aren't in the WP posts table, then a custom table would be the way to go.